# Error decomposing gcc command into separate compile and link steps

Tags: c++, gcc

I am getting a linker error building a simple project using scons. The example commands show integrated compiling and linking of program binaries, which scons does not do (though I probably could force it to, I'd rather not if possible).

This command works fine:

```
gcc -o main.exe main.cpp C:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.rc.data -s -static -Os -IC:\raylib\raylib\src -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

Whereas these two fail:

```
g++ -o main.o -c -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -Os -static -IC:\raylib\raylib\src main.cpp
ld -o mains.exe c:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.rc.data -s -static main.o -LC:\raylib\raylib\src -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

Resulting in:

```
c:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\ld: cannot find -lopengl32
c:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\ld: cannot find -lgdi32
c:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\ld: cannot find -lwinmm
```

Any insights? I'm not particularly familiar with the .rc.data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to get gcc's library search path:

```bash
]$ gcc -x cpp-output -E -v /dev/null 2>&1 | grep LIBRARY_PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../
/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

see if the missing libraries are in any of those directories, and if they are then add them to the `ld` invocation as `-L<path>` option.

EDIT

To see `ld` search path when it is called on its own, I think this should work:

```bash
]$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | sed 's/;/\n/g'
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
 SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

When you eliminate duplicates you'll notice that `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/` is an additional directory that is being searched when linking with `gcc` (your first command) but not when linking directly with `ld`.

But that's on my machine. On yours it will probably be a bit different.

Comment: Interesting thought. But why would the first command, which has no library path specification, work while the second pair does not?

Comment: `gcc` has a default library path, the one from the answer. The first command calls `ld` internally and passes those directories. But when `ld` is called on its own, it only searches through directories configured in `ld.conf`. It is possible that in the first case more directories are being searched and the missing libraries are in one of those. I updated the answer.

Comment: Fascinating, I did not know that. I was able to use that to get further. Thanks.